# How to refactor away redundant getter/setter methods?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing class with mutex guarded members that looks like this (class MembersNeedThreadSafe)...

```
// Just fake a mutex guard interface.  Obviously doesn't do anything
class Mutex
{
  public:
    struct Guard
    {
      Guard(Mutex & M) { };
    };
};

// This is the class I want to redesign.
class MembersNeedThreadSafe {
  Mutex M;

  int i;
  double k;
  // And a dozen more variables

  public:
  void SetI (int foo) { Mutex::Guard G(M); i = foo; }
  int GetI (void) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return i; }

  void SetK (double foo) { Mutex::Guard G(M); k = foo; }
  double GetK (void) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return k; }
  // And two dozen more methods
};

int main (void) {
  MembersNeedThreadSafe bar;

  bar.SetI(5);
  bar.SetK(6.0);

  double d = bar.GetK();

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to refactor the class MembersNeedThreadSafe into a design more like this, but it does not compile, complaining about the invalid use of non-static data members.

```
template <typename T, Mutex & M> class LockedVar {
  typedef LockedVar<T, M> my_type;
  T value;

  public:
  void Set(T const & foo) { Mutex::Guard G(M); value = foo; }
  T const & Get (void) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return value; }
};

// I want the class to look like this...
class MembersNeedThreadSafe {
  Mutex M;

  public:
  LockedVar <int, M> i;
  LockedVar <double, M> k;
  // And a dozen more variables
};

// This allows the code to run.
int main (void) {
  MembersNeedThreadSafe bar;

  bar.i.Set(5);
  bar.k.Set(6.0);

  double d = bar.k.Get();

  return 0;
}
```

So.... how can I refactor the first code block's `MembersNeedThreadSafe` class such that I don't have to write a redundant getter and setter method for each member?

*Addendum:*
I know I can use a design like this...

```
template <typename T> class LockedVar {
  typedef LockedVar<T> my_type;
  T value;
  Mutex & M;

  public:
  LockedVar (Mutex & foo) : M(foo) { }
  void Set(T const & foo) { Mutex::Guard G(M); value = foo; }
  T const & Get (void) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return value; }
};
```

But when I do so, sizeof(int) == 4, while sizeof(LockedVar) == 16 in my compiler (gcc 4.8.2), which throws a kind of red flag for me.  It seems like I should be able to solve this problem by using the mutex as a template argument, and I would like to know how to do so if possible.

Comment: It may seem that way to you, but it would be wrong. You're mixing compile-time and runtime concepts. Your addendum is the "correct" way to do this (the questionability of *that* left to stand on its own merit).

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I do not understand why this needs to touch runtime concepts.  While the addresses of the objects are not known at runtime, the class offsets (eg. `&MembersNeedThreadSafe::M`, `&MembersNeedThreadSafe::i`, are all known at compile time.  The compiler should be able to access M from within i without being told M's address at runtime, as long as i and M are members of the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to modify `LockedVar` a bit :

```
template <typename T> class LockedVar {
  typedef LockedVar<T> my_type;
  T value;

  public:

  void Set(T const & foo, Mutex & M ) { Mutex::Guard G(M); value = foo; }
  T const & Get (Mutex & M) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return value; }
};
```

---

Also, if you have that being repeated over and over, although it may not be very nice looking, you can create a macro :

```
#define IMPL_SET_GET( t, x ) \
    t x; \
    void Set##x (int foo) { Mutex::Guard G(M); x = foo; } \
    int Get##x (void) { Mutex::Guard G(M); return x; }

// This is the class I want to redesign.
class MembersNeedThreadSafe {
  Mutex M;


  // And a dozen more variables

  public:
      IMPL_SET_GET( int, i );
      IMPL_SET_GET( int, k );

  // And two dozen more methods
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your design is problematic to start with, the granularity of your locks allows for interactions such as:

```
// Thread 1                           // Thread 2
if (x.GetI() != 0) {

                                      x.SetI(0);

    return y / x.GetI();
}
```

In general you would prefer to:

1. Lock the object
2. Execute all the actions that need be done atomically
3. Unlock the object

A simple way to do so:

```
class Data {
public:
    friend class Behavior;

    Data(): i(3), k(7) {}

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    int i;
    int k;
}; // class Data

class Behavior {
public:
    explicit Behavior(Data& data): ref(data), guard(ref.mutex) {}

    int GetI() const { return ref.i; }
    void SetI(int i) { ref.i = i; }

    int GetK() const { return ref.k; }
    void SetK(int k) { ref.k = k; }

private:
    Data& ref;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard;
}; // class Behavior
```

Note that the mutex is only locked once (in the constructor of `Behavior`) and you don't have to repeat it at each and every getter and setter.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not at liberty to redesign the code to that extent.  This is an existing code base designed around the practice of making a copy of the retrieved object when you call Get(), and using that copy for further operations, so your scenario is not really one of concern.  Get() and Set() are understood to be highly granular.

Additionally, this does not seem to help me get away from having a repetitive GetX() and SetX() method defined for every member.

Comment: @QuestionC: Indeed, it does not, but why is it a concern ? Typing is cheap, and it's immediately understandable to any reader.

Comment: I see this as a [Once and Only Once](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OnceAndOnlyOnce) kind of problem.  I'm also very typo prone.

The other thing is... in principle this should be possible, so I want to know how to do it.

Comment: @QuestionC: I would disagree on the qualification here. The principle of getters and setters is to hide data behind functions so that you can *change the implementation* of the function. Therefore, the fact that two setters look similar is *an accidental property*, not *an essential property*; it may be that in two weeks one of the setter implementation will have to change but not the other because they interact with completely uncorrelated items. The only guaranteed common behavior here is the locking, which is always required for correctness, and that I addressed here by factoring it out.